# All Plugins not work in PhoneGap 3.0.0 (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, cordova

I'm doing simple example in phonegap for android (phonegap 3.0.0). I have ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse.

I'm doing everything exactly like this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide, but use command phonegap in console.

I got next example code: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader.

But when I try to run the application on the device I get the following error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.core.FileUtils

Help me. please!

Comment: what is your device version ?

Comment: I use emulation device - Nexus S. Android - 4.2.2

Comment: there is one folder for library file What is name lib or libs  ?

Comment: did you solved your problem? what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are in Eclipse:Then try elliminating phonegap lib dependences from Build Path and after that Proyect > Clean

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it changing the lines in config.xml

```
<feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

by this:

```
<feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line in your 'config.xml' file

```
`<param name="onload" value="true" /> `
```

as show below

```
 <feature name="File">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
     <!-- <param name="onload" value="true" /> -->
 </feature>
 <feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer"/>
  </feature>
```